# .Net Core 3 Windows Auth stops receiving credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, windows-authentication, .net-core-3.1

So I've been using the following code to get windows user-name within my .NET Core 2 web applications.  However, I'm trying to use the same method in .NET Core 3 and it works, but periodically it will just stop working and I have to restart the application in order for it to start working.  I'm not sure whether it's a timeout or something else.

Here's the code that I'm using within my Authentication controller

**AuthController.cs**

```
public AuthController() 
{
}

[Authorize]
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
    var userName = User.Identity.Name;
}
```

Like I said before, this usually works fine.  But on occasion it stops working completely till I restart the application.  The issue I get is a `NullReferenceException` on the User object itself.  Is there something new in .NET Core 3 or is there something that I'm just completely missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Joe,`OnActionExecuting` seems to be the method in Action Filter,why did you add [Authorize] attribute on this method?And what is your Startup.cs?Be sure call the middleware in the order like below:`UseRouting` , `UseAuthentication`, `UseAuthorization`, and `UseEndpoints`.

Comment: @Rena I had to add [Authorize] because we needed to enable Anonymous Authentication along side Windows Auth in order to get CORS to work correctly.  So then we needed this attribute tag in order to get the user's windows credentials at all.  
As far as the startup goes I call the middleware in this order: `UseDeveloperExceptionPage`, `UseHttpsRedirection`, `UseRouting`, `UseCors`, `UseAuthentication`, `UseAuthorization`, `UseEndpoints`, `UseOpenApi`, `UseSwaggerUi3`